# Does Landsat 9 Collection 2 Level 2 need any corrections?

Tags: landsat

I'm confused about choosing which level should I use to collect data for my final project. I'm still confused about the corrections in Landsat col2 level 1 and level 2. some thread has said that level 2 is atmospherically corrected.

Did I still need to do radiometric and geometric corrections to Landsat9 col2 level 2?